# using vtk on apple silicon m1

Tags: python, vtk, qvtkwidget

i'm trying to run this function using vtk on a mac m1. i think the problem is with my OS and not the code itself since on another OS like windows it works

```
def get_thumbnail(PDF, axis):
    ## some code that work and create the actor
    renderer = vtkRenderer()  
    renderer.AddActor(actor)

    window = vtkRenderWindow()  

    window.SetOffScreenRendering(1)

    window.AddRenderer(renderer)


    interactor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()  

    interactor.SetInteractorStyle(vtkInteractorStyleImage())  
    window.SetInteractor(interactor)
    ## HERE THE CODE GIVES THE ERROR
    window.Render()
    
    w2if = vtkWindowToImageFilter()  # noqa
    w2if.SetInput(window)
    w2if.Update()

    return w2if
```

getting the following error the problem suggest that i have to handle the invalidation on the Main Thread is there a way to do so that provide vtk itself

```
2024-02-11 21:29:43.958 python[29661:3966927] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018cb27154 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018c6464d4 objc_exception_throw + 60
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018cb503a0 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
        3   AppKit                              0x000000018fcf0a00 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 320
        4   AppKit                              0x000000018fcdecd4 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 816
        5   AppKit                              0x000000018fcde998 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 48
        6   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.3.dylib    0x000000010ad8fdf8 _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow13CreateAWindowEv + 1280
        7   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.3.dylib    0x000000010ad90440 _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow5StartEv + 64
        8   libvtkRenderingUI-9.3.dylib         0x0000000104ff13b0 _ZN30vtkCocoaRenderWindowInteractor10InitializeEv + 384
        9   libvtkRenderingCore-9.3.dylib       0x0000000106ea4574 _ZN15vtkRenderWindow6RenderEv + 148
        10  libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.3.dylib    0x000000010ae2f41c _ZN21vtkOpenGLRenderWindow6RenderEv + 104
        11  libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.3.dylib    0x000000010ad904d8 _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow6RenderEv + 24
        12  vtkRenderingOpenGL2.cpython-39-darw 0x000000010e5c8cb4 _ZL29PyvtkCocoaRenderWindow_RenderP7_objectS0_ + 136
        13  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x000000010291e870 cfunction_call + 172
        14  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dab70 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 360
        15  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad25c call_function + 536
        16  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        17  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        18  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        19  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        20  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        21  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa648 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23396
        22  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ae0a4 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2860
        23  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db294 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236
        24  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa648 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23396
        25  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        26  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        27  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa350 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22636
        28  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        29  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        30  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa350 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22636
        31  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        32  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        33  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa350 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22636
        34  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        35  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028da998 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 272
        36  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db674 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 148
        37  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x000000010293ef7c slot_tp_call + 104
        38  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dab70 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 360
        39  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad25c call_function + 536
        40  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        41  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028ee260 gen_send_ex + 308
        42  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029a9da0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21180
        43  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ae0a4 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2860
        44  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db294 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236
        45  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        46  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa3f0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22796
        47  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ae0a4 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2860
        48  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db294 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236
        49  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dd448 method_vectorcall + 168
        50  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        51  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa3f0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22796
        52  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        53  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dd448 method_vectorcall + 168
        54  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        55  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        56  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        57  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dd448 method_vectorcall + 168
        58  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        59  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        60  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ae0a4 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2860
        61  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db294 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236
        62  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dd448 method_vectorcall + 168
        63  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        64  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        65  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        66  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028da998 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 272
        67  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db674 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 148
        68  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x0000000102940320 slot_tp_init + 104
        69  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x0000000102937800 type_call + 372
        70  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dab70 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 360
        71  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad25c call_function + 536
        72  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa374 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22672
        73  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        74  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        75  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa350 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22636
        76  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        77  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dd55c method_vectorcall + 444
        78  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa648 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23396
        79  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        80  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        81  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa350 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22636
        82  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        83  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029ad1fc call_function + 440
        84  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029aa350 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22636
        85  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028db34c function_code_fastcall + 112
        86  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001028dd4d4 method_vectorcall + 308
        87  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x0000000102a448c4 t_bootstrap + 72
        88  libpython3.9.dylib                  0x00000001029f5448 pythread_wrapper + 28
        89  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018c9cffa8 _pthread_start + 148
        90  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018c9cada0 thread_start + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

Comment: That does look like a problem with VTK.  I'd suggest asking over at the VTK Discourse (discourse.vtk.org).